# org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter convert some classes to one(or class+parameter to one class)

Tags: java, spring, converters

I have `org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter`

```
@Component
public class CatalogConverter implements Converter<ServiceCatalogType, Catalog> {

  @Override
  public Catalog convert(ServiceCatalogType source) {
    Catalog catalog = new Catalog();
    //convert
    return catalog;
  }
}
```

And I register this converter:

```
@Configuration
public class ConvertersConfig {

  private final CatalogConverter catalogConverter;

  @Autowired
  public ConvertersConfig(CatalogConverter catalogConverter) {
    this.catalogConverter = catalogConverter;
  }

  @Bean(name="conversionService")
  ConversionService conversionService() {
    ConversionServiceFactoryBean factoryBean = new ConversionServiceFactoryBean();
    HashSet<Converter> converters = new HashSet<>();
    converters.add(catalogConverter);
    factoryBean.setConverters(converters);
    factoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();
    return factoryBean.getObject();
  }

}
```

But I need pass some parameter to my custom converter. I have some ways:

1. Pass it in constructor - but how can register this converter?
2. Use wrapper

   class Wrapper{
    private ServiceCatalogType catalog;
    private String uuid;
   }

and change converter like this:

```
implements Converter<ServiceCatalogType, Wrapper>
```

Or maybe Spring has another way?

**EDIT**

I need next.

in service:

```
pulic void send() {

ServiceCatalogType cs = getServiceCatalogType();//get from net
User user = getUser();//get from db
//convert cs+user to Catalog(all cs fields+ some user fields to catalog)
Catalog  catalog = conversionService.convert(cs, user, Catalog.class);

}
```

**EDIT2**

Wrapper implementation:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class CatalogWrapper {
  private ServiceCatalogType serviceCatalogType;
  private User user;
}


CatalogWrapper wrapper = new CatalogWrapper(getServiceCatalog(), getUser);
catalog = conversionService.convert(wrapper, Catalog.class);
```

Comment: Remove `@Component` create an `@Bean` to create the `CatalogConverter` and inject the dependencies. Or just create a constructor for those dependencies. Spring still will create and auto wire it. Also use the proper way to register the converter by implementing the `addFormatters` method of the `WebMvcConfigurer`.

Comment: I can not set parameter on congiguration phase. I get it in runtime and I need pass it to converter

Comment: What parameters do you need? That isn't really clear from your question. You state you need something int he constructor. Which constructor, the converter, the `Catalog`? I don't see how a wrapper could solve this... What is it you are trying to achieve. If you aren't simply converting from type x to type y but need more information then you shouldn't be using a converter.

Comment: @ M. Deinum  I eddited question

Comment: If that is your use case then don't use a `Converter` but rather create a regular component that does that for you. That isn't what the `Converter` s are meant/designed for.

Comment: @ M. Deinum I get an object generated with JAXB and I need convert it to Domain object, but also I need add some fields to domain object from another place(DB)

Comment: The fact that you need to "convert" something doesn't mean you must use a `Converter`. Those are for the simple cases of type x to type y conversions (`String` to `LocalDate` for example) but not for these complex cases. Write a regular class that has that knowledge and use that, don't try to shoehorn that into a `Converter` and the `ConversionService`

Comment: @ M. Deinum Thank you! you confirmed my assumption that this is a bad idea.